# Issue loading quaqua 64 libraries

Tags: java, macos, 64-bit, java-native-interface, quaqua

Every time my app loads I get the following error in the console:

> Warning: class ch.randelshofer.quaqua.osx.Application couldn't load library "quaqua64". java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no quaqua64 in java.library.path

I thought this would be resolved by adding `libquaqua64.jnlib` to the resource directory that contain my `libquaqua.jnlib` and `quaqua.jar`, but after I did this the console error still persists.  Anyone experiencing this?  Is there something else I need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to add it to my build.  Adding the libquaqua64.jnilib should do the trick for the warning I described.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a silly question, but after you copied in the `libquaqua64.jnilib` file, did you re-start the JVM?

I took a look at the code in `ch/randelshofer/quaqua/osx/OSXApplication.java` (Quaqua 5.4.1), and it will not re-try loading the JNI library if it fails the first time.

Comment: I imagine that this will sound like an even sillier question but how would I restart the JVM?  So the answer to your question is no ;)

Comment: Just quit your application and then re-start it.